# Django file download?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have two views "ans_page" and "downloads", where "ans_page" generates a file (library.csv) into a directory "output", further "ans_page" render an html page called "ans.html" it shows a table with data and a button just beneath the table to download a file from a directory "output" which is a part of an app called **FragBuild**, button is provided with a hyperlink which is associated with "Downloads" views URL, my expectation is that if some one click on the download button it should start a download but  it showing an error instead like given bellow:

View

```
def Downloads(request):

    file_path = os.path.join(os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0],'output','library.csv')
    file_wrapper = FileWrapper(file(file_path,'rb'))
    file_mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(file_path)
    response = HttpResponse(file_wrapper, content_type=file_mimetype )
    response['X-Sendfile'] = file_path
    response['Content-Length'] = os.stat(file_path).st_size
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str('library.csv')
```

and URL like this:

```
url(r'^ans_page/Downloads$', views.Downloads, name='Downloads'),
```

a button in html to initiate download like this:

```
<div class="">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" style="width:40; margin-bottom: 30px; margin-left: 300px "><a href="{% url 'Downloads' %}"> Download Peptide as CSV file  </a> </button>
</div>
```

But when i clicked on a button to initiate download it shows an error:

> ValueError at /ans_page/Downloads
>   The view FragBuild.views.Downloads didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

How can I solve this problem i have struggle a lot.

Comment: simple add `return response`

Comment: It was the dumbest mistake I have ever done.. How can I forget this thanks.. its working now..